# How to load initial data into ModelMultipleChoiceField - Django 1.6

Tags: django-forms, django-views

I'm creating my first site using Django and having trouble loading initial data into a ModelForm linked to the built in Django group table.

Right now, users can go to a group page and select from an array of groups they would like to join. When they return to the page later, they see the same list of options/checkboxes again with no indication of which groups they already belong to.

I can't figure out how to have the intial group data load into the form, such that if you are already a member of "group 1" for example, that checkbox is already checked.  I would also like to have it so that you could uncheck a box, and so when you submit the form you could be leaving some groups and joining others at the same time.  Any help appreciated! My code below:

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):        
    groupOptions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), label = "Choose your groups",
                                                  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['groupOptions']


def groupSelect(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GroupForm (request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            group = form.cleaned_data['groupOptions']
            request.user.groups = group
            return render (request, 'groups/groupSelect.html' , {'form':form})
    else:

        form = GroupForm()
        return render (request, 'groups/groupSelect.html' , {'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a few days and some trial and error, but figured this one out on my own. Just needed to modify the second to last line in the code above. The ModelForm loads all available groups as options, and the line below causes the groups the user already belongs to to be checked.

form = GroupForm(initial={ 'groupOptions': request.user.groups.all() })